# Converting a tensor to an array - Tensorflow JS

Tags: javascript, tensorflow.js

I run a Keypoints detection model using tfjs and then post process it (still using tfjs).
Then I use dataSync() on the final tensor in order to process it using JS.
The dataSync() takes about 4 times more than the inference + post-processing time.
I guess that it happens because dataSync() pulls the data from the GPU.
Is there a way to make this process faster?
Here's the code that I am using:

```
let output = model.execute(input_image_tensor);
let kpts = postProcess(output);
renderKpts(kpts.dataSync());
```

Thank you.

Comment: Odd behavior, I've never had this issue with it. Could you profile the code and share the results here?

Comment: I profiled the code using tf.time() and this is what I got: KernelMs: 0.01, wallTimeMS: 62.3, uploadWaitMs: 0, downloadWaitMs: 52.8. I hope that it helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`dataSync()` pulls data from specific tensor, so it depends on tensor size - what is the value of `kpts.shape`?
there is no chance if its just a few keypoints that it takes more than a milisecond.

** update **

just tried using `webgl` backend, it's around ~5 microseconds

```js
const tensor = tf.randomNormal([1, 4, 3]);
const time0 = performance.now();
const data = tensor.dataSync();
const time1 = performance.now();
console.log({ size: tensor.size, time: time1 - time0 });
```

```json
{ "size": 12, "time": 0.004999995231628418 }
```

Comment: It's very odd to me too. The shape is: [1, 4, 3], size: 12. Relatively small. Can it be a backend issue (using webgl)? Thank you!

Comment: i've updated answer since i cannot add js code to a comment, it's pretty fast in my case

Comment: Thanks a lot for checking. Is there a possibility that since I read pixels and find kpts on an image, that dataSync() pulls ALL the tensors (including the tensors that represent the image and not only this specific tensor)?

Comment: not possible, i do that all the time. is there some other async op running on gpu at the same time? could be that it's waiting for a sync lock, but that's just a wild guess.